# Use jquery sortable but sort only specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, thymeleaf

I am using jQuery sortable function and it works.
I'm also using thymeleaf.

My code looks something like this:

```
<div id="container">
        <div th:each = "drawer : &{drawers}" th:id="${drawer.id}">  
           <div class="sortableDrawer" th:include="drawer/drawer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mirror"></div>  
        </div>
```

Now I'm trying to sort every drawer in that div. I'm doing this and it works:

```
$('#container').sortable('toArray')
```

But this gives me an empty Array member which is the id of that tag with the class "mirror". I'm trying to get rid of this. Is it possible to somehow give a class, in this case "sortableDrawer" to the sortable function.

I want to do something like this:

```
$('#container').sortable(sortableDrawer, 'toArray')
```

Is there any way to do something like this or am I stuck with cleaning my Array from empty inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
 $('#container').sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'class' });
```

Comment: No, not really. This will make a list of all classes. I'm trying to make a list of id's but I'm trying to ignore some classes, or make jquery count only tags with a certain class.